# conflict using conda and pip in miniconda environment

Tags: python, pip, conda, tqdm, fast-ai

<strike>I found that if I try to install `tqdm` in miniconda environment (`pip insall tqdm`), it will fail, and the error then will persist also for other libraries searched by `pip`</strike>

**Update**

I tried many test, I come to the conclusion that `conda` and `pip` install conflicts in **miniconda** environment.

Step to reproduce:

```
conda create --name mlvision
```

test : is pandas and fastai there?

```
pip install pandas > pandas is there
```

now try to install opencv via conda

```
conda install opencv
[..]
```

now if I try `pip install`, I will get error:

```
pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/43/fd867e3347559845c8f993059d410c50a1e18709f1c4d4b3b47323a06a37/pandas-0.24.2-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _fdopendir$INODE64
  Referenced from: /Users/gg4u/Sites/miniconda3/envs/mlvision/bin/python
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _fdopendir$INODE64
  Referenced from: /Users/gg4u/Sites/miniconda3/envs/mlvision/bin/python
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

All installations via pip are now broken:

```
pip install fastai
Collecting fastai
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/14/385382da888f7e3ba24c726d95ea05563eb5e984ed97d5a24e74197f7848/fastai-1.0.54-py3-none-any.whl
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _fdopendir$INODE64
  Referenced from: /Users/gg4u/Sites/miniconda3/envs/mlvision/bin/python
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _fdopendir$INODE64
  Referenced from: /Users/gg4u/Sites/miniconda3/envs/mlvision/bin/python
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

also:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./envs/mlvision/lib/python3.7/site-packages (19.1.1)
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _fdopendir$INODE64
  Referenced from: /Users/gg4u/Sites/miniconda3/envs/mlvision/bin/python
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _fdopendir$INODE64
  Referenced from: /Users/gg4u/Sites/miniconda3/envs/mlvision/bin/python
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I conclude that conda install may conflict with pip install...

not sure if only when using `conda install opencv`

The way around I found is to install opencv as last package, once used I may have the missing reference:

```
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

and so I should install all packages via pip first, and last opencv...

How to solve conflicts in local conda environments ?

Tried to look at https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1429
but could not yet solve the issue.

I cannot proceed to install all the packages I need (some via conda, some via pip)

---

note python correctly poiting to local env:

```
which python
[your path]/miniconda3/envs/mlvision/bin/python
```

conda --version
conda 4.7.5

using Mac OS Mavericks 10.9.5 (if it matters)

Comment: As alternative to pip, I could use conda channels. Channels are other locations for conda to find distributions.
The thing is that for each package I have to search on the internet where could the package channel may be:

e.g. `conda install -c mlgill imutils` (for pip install imutils) or `conda install -c fastai fastai` (for pip install fastai). 

It is a workaround and still looking for better answer to this temporary solution.

Comment: Conda Channles doc -  https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html#Channel%20Customization

Comment: To search for a channel -  https://anaconda.org/search?q=imutil

Comment: I'm running into that same issue and still haven't find a solution. The problem started happening when I installed got manually in 10.9.5 and then run some command for bash to stop asking me to install developer tools...

Comment: @jimijazz try upvote the question and we'll see if it gets more attention for a definitive solution

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix `pip` with `conda` if you can help it. Get *everything* you can from `conda` first. Then use `pip` only to install packages that you cannot get from `conda`.

The packages `conda` installs are created with the Anaconda toolchain. And they have dependencies that make sure that those were also created with a compatible Anaconda toolchain. If you mix in stuff with `pip`, it can install compiled libraries that are not compatible with what the Anaconda packages require.

Comment: Hi @Roland Weber, I guessed that, I posted question for not all packages in pip are in conda.
After I use "conda install", "pip install" command fails. Maybe is there a workaround to use pip and install dependencies from conda if they are found, else proceed with pip ?